# Django's count fail in Oracle

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

I'm trying to make a query to a oracle database with this model:

```
class FCSTrunkValidation(Validation):
    card_transaction = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column='card_trnsctn_seq', primary_key=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, db_column='card_num')
    use_date = models.CharField(max_length=14, db_column='use_date')
    device = models.ForeignKey('TrunkDevice', db_column='device_id')
    agency_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, db_column='agency_id')
```

And this query:

```
# day is a datetime object
qs = FCSTrunkValidation.oracle_objects.all()
qs = qs.filter(use_date__startswith=day.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

When I do `qs.count()` I got this:

```
...
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 93, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 108, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 717, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 710, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
DatabaseError: ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage
```

However If I execute the query with the squirrel client I got the number, so it's django maybe doing additional querys that raise the error? How I can make the count work with django?

I though of use raw sql but then I got a problem escaping the `%` in the `LIKE` part

**Packages versions**

Python==2.7.4
Django==1.5.4
cx-Oracle==5.1.2
six==1.4.1

**Update 20131023**

Following the suggestion of @alko, I added a print statement in `django.db.backends.oracle.base` at line 709 like this:

```
print query, self._param_generator(params)
```

Then I executed that query with those params in Squirrel and still got the number of the count.

My manual query was:

```
select count(*) from TBAAD300 where AGENCY_ID=201 and USE_DATE LIKE '20130930%'
```

The query that django uses is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "TBAAD300" WHERE ("TBAAD300"."AGENCY_ID" = :arg0  AND "TBAAD300"."USE_DATE" LIKE TRANSLATE(:arg1 USING NCHAR_CS) ESCAPE TRANSLATE('\' USING NCHAR_CS) )
```

with `[u'201', u'20130930%']` as params

Then I executed the same query in Squirrel and the result is 130410, but when django does, the same error is raised, the full queries that were printed by the `print` statement are:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'AMERICA' []
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' []
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY LIKE TRANSLATE(:arg0 USING NCHAR_CS) ESCAPE TRANSLATE('\' USING NCHAR_CS) [u'X']
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "TBAAD300" WHERE ("TBAAD300"."AGENCY_ID" = :arg0  AND "TBAAD300"."USE_DATE" LIKE TRANSLATE(:arg1 USING NCHAR_CS) ESCAPE TRANSLATE('\' USING NCHAR_CS) ) [u'201', u'20130930%']
```

Comment: Did you execute it in squirrel with bind variables too?

Comment: Updated my answer with further questions :) And btw, do you have a dba that can help? Seems it is their scope of responsibility.

Comment: @alko I execute the exact same query with blind variables, and the dba are overseas and since they work for a provider of my company, they aren't interested in my problems with django.

Answer (score 0):

Is Oracle your prod db? ORA-02395 means IO restrictions, https://forums.oracle.com/thread/655458, seems your `count()` query leads to a full scan on a large table in db with restrictions on block reads per query.

I'd suggest to reconsider your data model, can you use `DateField` for `use_date` field and you replace your query with `filter(use_date__gte = ..., use_date___lte = ...)`? In this case you can drastically increase performance and IO usage by adding an index on use_date field, since count and alike queries can use it if appropriate.

**UPDATE (added here to fine format SQL)**

What is your Oracle DBMS version? Are you running statements under the same user credentials? What are resourse limits for your user ([this](http://psoug.org/reference/profiles.html) can help).

To check what resource consumtion metrics are, you can also run following command in sql client:

```
exec runstats_pkg.rs_start;
<YOUR statement>
exec runstats_pkg.rs_stop;
select * from stats where name like '%session logical reads%';
select * from stats where name like '%consistent gets%';
```

also an execution plan may be handy

```
set autotrace on;
<YOUR STATEMENT>
set autotrace off;
```

as described [here](http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/788-PX-Issues-Continued.html)

Comment: As I say in the quetion, I can perfectly execute the same query in the database with the Squirrel client and doesn't got that error. That's why I am asking if django count have aditional queries. Besides, unfortunately the model is designed by another team and I can't change the model.

Comment: I doubt that magic can happen due to client, so i dont beleive that sqls are equal. Can you provide SQL from squirrel, and sql executed by django? For the latter, run your script with logging set at `DEBUG` level; or simply temporary add `print query` just before 710 line in `/home/diegueus9/dev/odm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py`. And SQL plans for both woulbe of some help.